# SiriKit intent always times out on first run after build

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

After I first build and run my intents project, requesting something from Siri always returns with `Sorry, you will need to continue in the app`

However, it works every time after that until I rebuild.

I put breakpoints in handler:

```
override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
    return self
}
```

and in handle:

```
func handle(requestRide intent: INRequestRideIntent, completion: @escaping (INRequestRideIntentResponse) -> Void) {
...
}
```

The breakpoint in `handler` is hit a few seconds after Siri says `continue in app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SiriKit is very picky on waiting. Your first run will time out because of the time it takes Xcode to attach the debugger to Siri's process.

I've just learned to live with it.